# How can I search posts only in all of my groups, excluding other public groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-search

I'd like to be able to search for posts only in groups that I am a member of. However, Facebook only seems to allow me to search all groups, or a single group. How can I search for posts within all of my groups, but exclude other public groups?